# Finding Perfect Numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So finding the first 4 perfect numbers(being 6, 28, 496, 8192) using Haskell and there are a tonne of implementations out there. But currently I'm trying to design an efficient solution to find all the perfect numbers from 1 -> 1,000,000,000,000.

My current code looks like this:

```hs
sumDivisors a =
   foldr (\n -> let (q,r) = a `quotRem` n in
       if r==0 then (+ (n+q)) else id) 1
       [2..(floor . sqrt . fromIntegral $ a)]

isPerfect :: Integral a => a -> Bool
isPerfect n = n == sumDivisors n

upUntil :: Integral a => a -> [a]
upUntil n = filter isPerfect [1..n]
```

it can find up to 10000 fairly quick, but I need to be able to look further in an efficient timespace. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need a better algorithm, so look around on the Internet for one. Mathematicians are better experts on how to find perfect numbers efficiently than computer programmers are. https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106b/assignments/1-cpp/perfect is one description I found of an algorithm that seems capable of finding, at least, more perfect numbers than your exhaustive-search algorithm.

Comment: I've heard about the possibility of using Euclid-Euler theroem. This is supposed to help with the runtime if you can implement math terminology to code terminology. Also not sure how sending me C++ code is a "better algorithm" when the language at hand is Haskell but still, I appreciate the resource :)

Comment: You're supposed to actually read the article, not just notice what language the code samples are implemented in. The prose and the C++ both describe an improved algorithm, i.e. Euclid-Euler.